# C bmp header contains wrong information

Tags: c, bmp

I am trying to get the height and width of a bmp picture, however the values i am getting are incorrect and are not the actual size of the picture.
Here is my code for doing so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
FILE * Pic;
errno_t err;
int **PixelStrength;
int PictureWidth, PictureHeight;


err = fopen_s(&Pic, "d2.bmp", "r");
if (!err)
{

    fseek(Pic, 18, SEEK_SET);
    PictureWidth = fgetc(Pic);
    fseek(Pic, 22, SEEK_SET);
    PictureHeight = fgetc(Pic);
}


if (Pic)
{
    err = fclose(Pic);
}
}
```

I should note that this has worked for a small picture however not for any larger one. The pictures that i have tried are 640 x 480 yet the values i receive are 128 x 224. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 640 = 2*256 + 128; 480 = 256 + 224

Comment: I would recommend defining a header `struct` and reading the whole thing in, using functions to extract members in the correct endian fashion, or a byte array ditto.

Comment: Another issue: `fopen_s(&Pic, "d2.bmp", "r");` --> `fopen_s(&Pic, "d2.bmp", "rb");`  Add `b`.  Open file in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetc()` fetches a single byte from the file. The height and width values are stored as 32-bit little-endian. 640 is 0x280, and 480 is 0x1E0, so the values you are getting are 0x80 (128) and 0xE0 (224), just the low-order byte of the values.

Try something like

```
PictureWidth = fgetc(Pic);
PictureWidth += 256 * fgetc(Pic);
```

(Yes, they really are 32-bit values, which is four bytes, but it's unlikely that you'll run into a 70000-pixel wide BPM anytime soon).

Comment: I don't think you can depend on the `fgetc()` calls being executed left to right. Do them as separate statements.